# mcrypt methods are deprecated from PHP 7.x, need alternative

Tags: php, deprecated, mcrypt, paytm

The `mcrypt` related methods are removed from PHP 7.x.

We are using below methods which are deprecated in PHP 7.x.

- `mcrypt_get_block_size`
- `mcrypt_module_open`
- `mcrypt_generic_init`
- `mcrypt_generic`
- `mcrypt_generic_deinit`
- `mcrypt_module_close`

Is there any alternative methods which can used in integration.

Comment: The mcrypt methods haven't been removed, they're just deprecated since PHP 7.1. Ideally you should look to migrate to the `openssl_*` set of functions (or something higher level like libsodium) though, see https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong